# bad argument in call to fxml_stream:new(undefined, 65536)

Tags: erlang, xmpp, ejabberd, gen-server

I am not familiar with erlang and new to ejabberd. I am getting following 
error in crash.log.

```
2017-06-22 04:58:53 =CRASH REPORT====
crasher:
initial call: ejabberd_receiver:init/1
pid: <0.23584.370>
registered_name: []
exception exit: {{badarg,[{fxml_stream,new,[undefined,65536],[]},{ejabberd_receiver,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_receiver.erl"},{line,168}]},{gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,615}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,647}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]},[{gen_server,terminate,7,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,812}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
ancestors: [<0.358.0>,ejabberd_listener,ejabberd_sup,<0.62.0>]
messages: []
links: []
dictionary: []
trap_exit: false
status: running
heap_size: 610
stack_size: 27
reductions: 275
neighbours:

2017-06-22 07:05:00 =ERROR REPORT====
** Generic server <0.25047.377> terminating
** Last message in was {become_controller,undefined}
** When Server state == {state,#Port<0.5706277>,gen_tcp,none,undefined,65536,undefined,infinity}
** Reason for termination ==
** {badarg,[{fxml_stream,new,[undefined,65536],[]},{ejabberd_receiver,handle_call,3,[{file,"src/ejabberd_receiver.erl"},{line,168}]},{gen_server,try_handle_call,4,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,615}]},{gen_server,handle_msg,5,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,647}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,247}]}]}
```

Can anybody help me understand the issue here?

Comment: can you please share some more information in the description? For example the configuration you are using, what are you trying to setup, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/processone/ejabberd/issues/1796) in the bugtracker which is already fixed.